# How to add a all the remaining children (i.e a tree) to a selected node for a jstree?

Tags: django, jstree

i m working on django project on windows...my jstree is like this...

- root

  > > - parent1
  > > - parent2

  When I click on parent1 I want to add all of its remaining children (nodes and all sub nodes which is a json data) same with parent2 and so on. Basically when i click on parent then only it should get all its childrens

Comment: Are you looking for AJAX call when a node is opened? http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data

Comment: thank you...no i want it to be added when node is selected and i found the ans here https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jstree/3Kjfgmu84fo